# upload with ant - scp to multi host

Tags: ant, scp

i have 3 web server. I use ant script for upload my files to these servers. I want to upload only modified files. I use that code ;

```
<!-- APP 37 -->
<target name="2: Copy to Prod">
     <!-- upload the files to the new directory -->
    <echo message="FTP SERVER: ${remote.ftp.server_1}:${remote.ftp.port}" />
    <!-- APP 1 - 37 -->
    <scp todir="${remote.ftp.username}:${remote.ftp.password}@${remote.ftp.server_1}:${remote.ftp.dir}" trust="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <modified update="false"/>
        </fileset>
    </scp>

    <echo message="FTP SERVER: ${remote.ftp.server_2}:${remote.ftp.port}" />
    <!-- APP 2 - 38 -->     
    <scp todir="${remote.ftp.username}:${remote.ftp.password}@${remote.ftp.server_2}:${remote.ftp.dir}" trust="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <modified update="false"/>
        </fileset>
    </scp>
    <echo message="${remote.ftp.server_1} - ${remote.ftp.dir} transfer completed" />

    <echo message="FTP SERVER: ${remote.ftp.server_3}:${remote.ftp.port}" />
    <!-- APP 3 - 39 -->
    <scp todir="${remote.ftp.username}:${remote.ftp.password}@${remote.ftp.server_3}:${remote.ftp.dir}" trust="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <modified>
              <param name="cache.cachefile" value="localdev.cache"/>
            </modified>
        </fileset>
    </scp>

    <echo message="${remote.ftp.server_3} - ${remote.ftp.dir} transfer completed" />
</target>
```

But this code upload all files.
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem like this;

```
<fileset dir=".">
    <modified>
      <param name="cache.cachefile" value="localdev.cache"/>
    </modified>
</fileset>

<fileset dir=".">
    <modified>
      <param name="cache.cachefile" value="localdev_2.cache"/>
    </modified>
</fileset>

<fileset dir=".">
    <modified>
      <param name="cache.cachefile" value="localdev_3.cache"/>
    </modified>
</fileset>
```

thanks all